# Adding a map from a website into QGIS

Tags: qgis, web-mapping

I need to add a historical map from a website into QGIS. I installed the QuickMapServices Plugin and I tried to make new XYZ connections, but nothing appeared.

The website is: https://mapire.eu/en/map/secondsurvey-hungary/?layers=osm%2C5&bbox=2108467.652103985%2C6019839.160187972%2C2134246.039893161%2C6027482.863016489

I tried some variations of the URL too.

How should I modify the URL? 
 Is there another way to import somehow this historical map from the above-mentioned website?

Comment: At first glance there is no WMS-service ot that map, therefore adding it into QGis requires a raster map (worst possibility: screenshot) which needs to be georeferenced. Or ask the provider whether there is a chance to get the map as a georeferenced raster.

Comment: There is some sort of tile service behind the web page (tiles.mapire.eu) but I don't think there's any direct access to the service

Answer (score 3):

I think the quick answer here is that it's not possible to access the underlying tile service (tiles.mapire.eu) directly.  You should contact the web site provider to see if they can/will provide you access.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try it but there is a plugin : [web2qgis](https://github.com/tomchadwin/web2qgis) that claim to be able to do what you want

From the description :

> Load a webmap directly into QGIS
>
> Attempts to parse a remote webpage to import a webmap into a QGIS project

Let us know if it work in your case

Comment: You need QGIS3 for it, but it does not work on the requested page. It is able to retrieve vector data from a simple Openlayers or leaflet webmap (like those created with qgis2web).

Answer (score 1):

The tiles are protected via special cooky. If you directly try to access tiles (i.e. https://tiles.mapire.eu/mercator/secondsurvey-habsburg/hungary/13/4526/2865) you will receive 403 (forbidden) return code.

Without protection the QMS string will be https://tiles.mapire.eu/mercator/secondsurvey-habsburg/hungary/{z}/{x}/{y}

In [about](https://www.arcanum.hu/en/mapire/) of this cite:

> We present detailed and accurate countrywide mapping surveys in an innovative way.

Never understand such "innovations".